# Not catching Exception in server (unless I add a breakpoint)

Tags: java, eclipse, try-catch, breakpoints

So basically I have a try/catch where my catch is catching Exception. The purpose is to remove a client from the list of connected clients if a client disconnects without notifying the server. For some reason though its not catching. The weird part is that when I add a breakpoint at the catch (i'm using eclipse btw) it breaks and then when i continue, it catches and will continue to catch properly until I restart the server. At this point all the client does is it connects to the server and then dies. The server doesn't catch this and then stops responding if I try and close the server window. The only way to stop it if it doesn't catch is to terminate it.

So to clarify my code works, my issue is the solely with the catch not catching which results in the server not realizing that the client has left the server. Adding a breakpoint fixes it for some reason which is my problem.

Here is most of the code for the server:

```
35 public static ArrayList<Socket> list_sockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();
36 public static ArrayList<Integer> list_client_states = new ArrayList<Integer>();
37 public static ArrayList<DataPackage> list_data = new ArrayList<DataPackage>();
38
39 private static Runnable accept = new Runnable() {
40  @Override
41  public void run() {
42      new Thread(send).start();
43      new Thread(receive).start();
44      
45      while (true) {
46          try {
47              Socket socket = server.accept();
48              
49              ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
50              
51              String username = (String) ois.readObject();
52              
53              ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
54              oos.writeObject("Welcome...");
55              
56              list_clients_model.addElement(username + " - " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " - " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
57              list_client_states.add(0);
58              
59              list_data.add(new DataPackage());
60              list_sockets.add(socket);
61          }
62          catch (Exception e) {}  
63      }   
64  }
65 };
66
67 private static Runnable send = new Runnable() {
68  @Override
69  public void run() {
70      ObjectOutputStream oos;
71      
72      while (true) {
73          for (int i = 0; i < list_sockets.size(); i++){
74              try {
75                  oos = new ObjectOutputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getOutputStream());
76                  int client_state = list_client_states.get(i);
77                  oos.writeObject(client_state);
78                  
79                  oos = new ObjectOutputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getOutputStream());
80                  oos.writeObject(list_data);
81                  
82                  if (client_state == 1) { // Kicked by server
83                      disconnectClient(i);
84                      i--;
85                  }
86                  else if (client_state == 2) { // Server Disconnected
87                      disconnectClient(i);
88                      i--;
89                  }
90              }
91              catch (Exception e) {}
92          }
93      }
94  }
95 };
96
97 private static Runnable receive = new Runnable() {
98  @Override
99  public void run() {
100     ObjectInputStream ois;
101     
102     while (true) {
103        //System.out.println(list_sockets.size());
104        for (int i = 0; i < list_sockets.size(); i++) {
105             try {
106                 ois = new ObjectInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream());
107                 int receive_state = (Integer) ois.readObject();
108                 
109                 ois = new ObjectInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream());
110                 DataPackage dp = (DataPackage) ois.readObject();
111                 
112                 list_data.set(i, dp);
113                 
114                 if (receive_state == 1) { // Client disconnected by user
115                     disconnectClient(i);
116                     i--;
117                 }
118             }
119             catch (Exception e) { // Client Disconnected (Client didn't notify server about disconnecting)
120                 disconnectClient(i);
121                 i--;
122                 e.printStackTrace();
123                 
124             }
125         }
126     }
127 }
128 };
```

And the Server disconnect method:

```
public static void disconnectClient(int index) {
    try {
        list_clients_model.removeElementAt(index);
        list_client_states.remove(index);
        list_data.remove(index);
        list_sockets.remove(index);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Here is the exception I am getting when I add the breakpoint (it doesn't happen if I don't add it):

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ServerMain$3.run(ServerMain.java:105)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So as an update, it will also work if I uncomment line 103.
Also I mentioned in the comments that I'm following a tutorial this is the on i'm following for reference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFF0JRCFCH0

EDIT: So thank you azzurroverde, the problem was in fact that my lists wern't synchronized.
Changing lines 35-37 to the following fixed my issue and it now works fine:

```
35 public static List<Socket> list_sockets = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Socket>());
36 public static List<Integer> list_client_states = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
37 public static List<DataPackage> list_data = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<DataPackage>());
```

Comment: It might be that When you debug you make the socket handling reach a timeout, which leads to the exception you see.

Comment: What exception are you actually getting?

Comment: What causes the Exception? Can you print out a trace?

Comment: Well first thing to do is Catch SocketException not Exception. Hard to say what's going on here, guess would be disconnectClient is throwing another exception. Personally I'd add a write to a log with the message and stacktrace, before calling disconnect.

Comment: Can you show us your disconnectClient(i) method?

Comment: Which statement throws the exception? This is basic information that should always be included in a SO question.

Comment: Is java:105 the line where the exception occurs? Which line is that in your code?

Comment: Since there is a 
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
I am wondering if the parameter list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream() is correct. Do you know if the value is not null or something that would not work?

Comment: Why do you create two ObjectInputStream out of the same inputStream? (Same i)?
  ois = new ObjectInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream());

Comment: Ok so yeah line 105 is supposed to throw the exception that gets caught, however my problem is that nothing is getting caught unless I add a breakpoint. I don't even know if the program is getting to line 105 cause if I add a breakpoint it makes it work. Part of my problem is that i'm following a tutorial for creating a server as i'm somewhat new to dealing with network communication so i'm having some trouble following all of the code myself.

Comment: Can I suggest a very simple alternative to follow your execution? Add a println("1") at every line, so you see what it reaches without breackpoint. 
Anyway, which line is 105? We don't have line numbers ...

Comment: ah, yeah idk why I didn't think of that i'll try that. line 105 is ois = new ObjectInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream()); under the try.

Comment: Wait wait wait... Are you actually getting a exception? e.printStackTrace(); will throw the exception stack trace as if a real exception occurred when it was actually handled. Add a System.out.println("Catch Block") statement inside the handling code (i.e the catch block) and see if it gets executed.

Comment: Ok so I did what azzurroverde suggested and found out a little bit better whats going on as well as more confused than ever. I added this line just above line 103: System.out.println("2"); As expected it spams 2 infinitely but also the catch is now caught. However, as soon as I comment it out and restart the server it stops working again. I also put a println above line 104 however until I uncomment  the first println it never prints so its not even getting into the for loop unless I uncomment the println

Comment: Also, at which i does it does the exception occur? The first or the second? (i==0, i==1?)
println(i) inside the loop ...
Do you need to close the input before going to the next loop?
ios.close();

Comment: Are you reading your own output? :)

Comment: The exception when it occurs, occurs at i==0 Also I tried using ois.close(); before going to the next loop however it had no effect.

Comment: What is inside list_sockets? I mean how many elements are there, and which one is the first? How do you fill it up? What is list_sockets.get(0).getInputStream()?

Comment: ok just updated the post with the method that is filling list_sockets etc.

Comment: Well, the error is caused by:
list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream() at line 106 (before was 103).
We have to understand why ...

Comment: My feeling is that the input stream of a socket is the output stream of another. I mean, when you print out something, that gets taken as input stream of the first socket. If you print, it works because you have some input, if you don't, the socket gets reset. Can you write some loop to add input to a socket maybe?

Comment: what are the ports of the clients?

Comment: yeah the input for that the server is getting, is the output of a client that was or is connected. Normally the client would send a disconnect message to the server to notify it to remove that particular client from list_sockets. However if the client somehow exits without sending a disconnect message the server would try and access that input stream and fail thus throwing the catch which would remove that client from list_sockets. But for whatever reason the catch isnt being thrown unless I uncomment line 103 which is just a println which makes no sense at all to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: btw the clients/server are running over port 2406.

Comment: In line 103, can you put System.out.println(list_sockets.size()); instead of System.out.println("2");

Comment: I am wondering if it a problem of ArrayList synchronization ...

Comment: System.out.println(list_sockets.size()); outputs 0, and then catches properly, though same as before if I uncomment it the program stops catching again.

Comment: hold on if list_socket.size() is 0, then it would never enter the loop right? which means it would never hit the try/catch.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but can you please tell me which tool you used for prefixing line numbers?

Comment: actually I did all of the number lines manually haha if anyone else knows a good way that would be nice, so I did some more tests and the size properly = 1 when i use breakpoints, i'm beginning to see what you mean about the array being the problem now.

Comment: Also I updated main post, not sure if its part of the issue or not but I have a 3rd method send that is also a part of the server and deals with the arrays in question.

Comment: What about synchronizing the array then?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
 List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));

Comment: You need good synchronization strategies ... you have to many procedures working on the same arrays at the same time. The two loops, in send and receive, have operations that need to be done while there are no changes on the structures by others, from the beginning of one loop iteration to the end, including the check inside the for().

Comment: Ok just changed them to the List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...)); and it it works! Everything is now running properly and the catch is caught when it is supposed to! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's summarize the answer then, after this long discussion :)
The problem was that the ArrayList was not synchronized and different threads were accessing it at the same time leaving it in an unstable state

```
public static ArrayList<Socket> list_sockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();
```

The solution was to synchronize the array list:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```